# Return Attribute of Class Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Basically I have a table output on a page, `base` view. The headers (`milestones`) are dynamically integrated by passing the `Milestones` class and iterating through each with an `.each do`. The table rows are then initially generated by doing the same thing, pulling in `client`, `trade`, and `units`, into the first three columns. The rest of the columns should be dates (class `entry` attribute `due`) that are calculated by a lookup of sorts using the `client` and `trade` attributes accessible by the loop, and the `milestone` ID accessible by an array created when dynamically generating them for the headers. This all works correctly as it should, and the table generates fine.. however the dates are output as `#<Entry:0x000000056faa90>` and so on.

Now I have come across this problem before, and basically the fix was to add a class definition and tell it to return what I assume to be the attribute of that instance. For example:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :id,      presence:true
    validates :client,  presence:true

    def name
        return self.client
    end
end
```

And this works great, but only for how I access the client. Unfortunately I am accessing `entry.due` differently. Here are my relevant bits of code.

---

### base_controller.rb

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @trades = Trade.all
    @milestones = Milestone.all
    #@entries = Entry.all  #Didn't seem relevant to how I am trying to access the information.
  end
end
```

### entry.rb

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :trade
  belongs_to :milestone

  validates :client,    presence:true
  validates :trade,     presence:true
  validates :milestone, presence:true
  validates :due,       presence:true

  # Some of my trial and error; all to no avail.
  def due
    return self.due
  end

  def self.due
    return self.due
  end

  def pickDue(c,t,m)
    ret = self.select("date_format(due, '%m/%d/%Y')").where("client_id=? AND trade_id=? AND milestone_id=?", c, t, m).first
    return ret
  end
end
```

### base > index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="sort">
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>Trade</th>
      <th>Units</th>

      <% 
          ms = []
          @milestones.each do |milestone|
          ms.push(milestone)
      %>
        <th><%= milestone.name %></th>
      <% end %>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @trades.order("entered").last(10).each do |trade| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= trade.client.name %></td>
        <td><%= trade.name %></td>
        <td><%= trade.units %></td>

        <% ms.each do |msr| %>
            <td>
              <%= Entry.select("date_format(due, '%m/%d/%Y')").where("client_id=? AND trade_id=? AND milestone_id=?", trade.client, trade, msr).first %>
              <%#= Entry.pickDue(trade.client, trade, msr) %>
            </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

With this approach, I can load the page error-free, but instead of showing dates, I am shown objects like `#<Entry:0x000000056faa90>`.

If I add `.due` to the end of the selector:

```
<%= Entry.select("date_format(due, '%m/%d/%Y')").where("client_id=? AND trade_id=? AND milestone_id=?", trade.client, trade, msr).first.due %>
# undefined method `due' for nil:NilClass
```

If I add `.due` after anything else:

```
<%= Entry.due.select("date_format(due, '%m/%d/%Y')").where("client_id=? AND trade_id=? AND milestone_id=?", trade.client, trade, msr).first %>
<%= Entry.select("date_format(due, '%m/%d/%Y')").due.where("client_id=? AND trade_id=? AND milestone_id=?", trade.client, trade, msr).first %>
<%= Entry.select("date_format(due, '%m/%d/%Y')").where("client_id=? AND trade_id=? AND milestone_id=?", trade.client, trade, msr).due.first %>
# stack level too deep
```

I have tried dozens of different methods acquired through several days of looking into this with no luck. Besides the current situation where it outputs objects instead of the object attribute, the next closest I've come I think is when I got an error saying it could not find the `due` method for an `ActiveRecord` object, but I don't remember how got to that error.

I would really appreciate any input.

Comment: How is the attribute, "client", defined in the class "Client"? Do you have a column named "client" in the table "clients"?

Comment: Are you sure your query is returning records?

Comment: @YosepKim Yes, `client` is a column in the `clients` table. @DickieBoy Yes, the query was returning records in the correct places, they were just coming back as objects instead of the object's attribute that I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I would get rid of that trial and error code in your model, and then in your view you can just call this:

```
Entry.where(client: trade.client, milestone: msr, trade: trade).pluck(:due)
```

This goes inside your milestone loop in your view, like this:

```
    <% ms.each do |msr| %>
        <td>
          <%= Entry.where(client: trade.client, milestone: msr, trade: trade).pluck(:due).first %>
        </td>
    <% end %>
```

Pluck returns an array of values from the columns you specify (see [the relevant section of the RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck), so note that the `.first` method is the `Array#first` method, not the `ActiveQuery#first` method. You could even make a query that passes in all of the milestones at once instead of running a query for each milestone, thereby preventing an N+1 query situation.

That would be:

```
<% Entry.where(client: trade.client, trade: trade, milestone: ms).pluck(:due).each do |entry_due_date| %>
  <td>
    <%= entry_due_date %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Lastly, while I gave you the code for the SQL query in the view, it is generally considered a bad practice in Rails to write SQL queries in your view, and you should probably make this into a method in your Entry model.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly and it taught me something new. I did want to pull in all values at once because I know from other languages that is best practice, but I work progressively and wanted to try to code this systematically first to grasp an understanding. I will take your suggestion into account and work on doing that part next. I truly appreciate your help!!

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be looking for `attributes` method.

```
entry = Entry.new
entry.attributes #=> returns a hash of key-value attribute pairs
```